# Entity Framework extension method to get a viewmodel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a model with a one to many relation

```
public class Project
{
    [Required]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(512)]
    [Required]
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }        
    public Category Category{ get; set; }
    public Guid? CategoryId{ get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    [Required]
    public Guid Id{ get; set; }
    public string CategoryName{ get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, a category can have many projects.

In my controller I have this code, that brings me a list of my viewModel.

```
public class ProjectViewModel
{      
     public string CategoryName{ get; set; }
     public IEnumerable<TProjectBasic> Tipo { get; set; }
}

public class TProjectBasic
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Tipo { get; set; }
}

private List< ProjectViewModel> GetProjectVM()
{
        List<ProjectViewModel> lista = new List<ProjectViewModel>();

        lista = _dbContext.Category.GroupJoin(_dbContext.Project,
                c => a.Id,      //  key on  the left    side    
                p => p.CategoryId,            //    key on  the right   side,
                (Category,Project) =>            // what    to  do  once    matched
                            new ProjectViewModel
                           {
                               CategoryName=Category.CategoryName,
                                MProject=Project
                            }).ToList();
        return lista;
    }
}
```

The previous code IS NOT working for my `ProjectViewModel`, it is working if my view model is the following

```
public class TipoProyectoViewModel
{      
    public string CategoryName{ get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Project> MProject{ get; set; }
}
```

My idea is to display my projects grouped by `CategoryName`, for instance

```
Category = House
{
   { Id = 1, ProjectName = "my project" }
   { Id = 2, ProjectName = "my project2" }
}

Category = Cars
{
   { Id = 3, ProjectName = "my project3" }
   { Id = 5, ProjectName = "my project5" }
}
```

How can I rewrite my code to display data in the format I am showing? Thanks a lot

Comment: You can just use a `.GroupBy` on your Products -  `_dbContext.Projects.GroupBy(x => x.Category.name).Select(x => new ProjectViewModel { ...`

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
public class Project
{
    [Required]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(512)]
    [Required]
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }        
    public Category Category{ get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Category")]
    public Guid? CategoryId{ get; set; }

}
  public class Category
{
    [Required]
    public Guid Id{ get; set; }
    public string CategoryName{ get; set; }
    public ICollaction<Project> Projects{ get; set; }
}

var categories = _dbContext.Category.Include(c=>c.Projects).GroupBy(e=>e.CategoryName)
.Select(e=> new TipoProyectoViewModel(){ CategoryName = e.Key , MProject = e.Select(c=>c.Project) });
```

Comment: Hello thank you, it seems everything good, but when you write in the last part MProject=e.Key.Projects, I can not use that , intellisense does not show key.Projects. An error message appears> string does not contain a definition for Projects,